# Cognito unconfirmed user accounts using AWS CLI Command line

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-cli

```html
aws --profile xx cognito-idp list-users  --user-pool-id xxx --filter cognito:user_status="CONFIRMED"
```

An error occurred (InvalidParameterException) when calling the ListUsers operation: Error while parsing filter. Let me know what is wrong in that code.